# Find a transducer that maps a given deterministic process to another

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata, hidden-markov-models, transducers

Let $S$ denote a deterministic process which generates a certain string, described through a Hidden Markov Model. More specifically, for a process with alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ and $n$ hidden states, the description is given through the $n\times n$ transition matrices $T^{(a)}$ with elements $T^{(a)}_{ij}=Pr(s_{t+1}=j,A_t=a|s_t=i)$, which encode the probability of being in state $i$ and upon emitting symbol $a$ transitioning to state $j$. For example the process for generating the sequence $...010101010101..$ would have the representation
$$
T^{(0)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\,,\, \, 
T^{(1)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

One can also construct deterministic transducers, that is, input-dependent Hidden Markov Models that take a deterministic process to another deterministic process. The description is similarly given through input-dependent transition matrices $T^{(b|a)}$, with elements $T^{(b|a)}_{ij}=Pr(s_{t+1}=j,B_t=a|s_t=i,A_t=a)$. For example, a deterministic transducer with two states and input and output alphabets $\{0,1\}$ that either performs the identity or a bit flip could be represented as
$$
T^{(0|0)}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\,,\, \, 
T^{(1|0)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\,,\, \, 
T^{(0|1)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\,,\, \, 
T^{(1|1)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and would map the previous defined process of alternating zero and one to the process that generates $...001100110011...$. This process' description would be
$$
\hat{P}^{(0)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \, \,\,
\hat{P}^{(1)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
After these definitions and example, I am ready to state my questions.

**Question 1:** Given two known processes $S$ and $P$ how can one find a transducer that maps one to the other (in general there is no unique solution). More importantly, is there a way to construct a transducer with minimal amount of hidden states? Is there an algorithm to do any of these two tasks?

**Question 2:** Given a representation of process $S$ with a HMM with $n$ states, how can one find the representation that has minimal number of states? In other words, is there an algorithm that takes a process with $n$ states and generates another with $m$, such that $m\leq n$ and equality if and only if the original representation of the process is already minimal?

PS: I do not have a formal background in CS but only maths, so please forgive me if my notation is weird and I am lacking in knowledge of basic results.

Comment: What do you mean by mapping one process to another?  What is the definition of that?

Answer (score 1):

Your processes are just [deterministic finite-state transducers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer).

Question 1: It sounds like you are asking, given two deterministc finite-state transducers $S,P$, can we find a deterministic finite-state transducer so that $S \circ T = P$.

Question 2: You seem to be asking if we can minimize a deterministic finite-state transducer.

I don't know the answer to either of these questions -- they are very reasonable questions -- but hopefully this gives you some terminology you can search for.

Regarding Question 1, I believe you can find a non-deterministic finite-state transducer $T$ such that $S \circ T = P$.  Basically, you use the product composition; $T$ tracks the sequence of states traversed by $S$, and simultaneously guesses the sequence of states traversed by $P$.  Maybe you could construct such a non-deterministic transducer, then check whether it can be determinized.

Regarding Question 2, Wikipedia claims that transducers can be minimized and gives a reference.